# Interesting questions appearing only once

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions, interesting-page

When I login to Stack Overflow, in the Questions tab I see a tab for interesting questions. but it never appears when I go to another tabs and come back to the Questions tabs.

Why is it so?

Comment: FYI, you can just click on the logo to go back to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *interesting* tab is part of the homepage, not of the *Questions* section. Click the logo to get back to the homepage and see the *interesting* tab again. They're subtly different in more ways if you look at it, only the *Featured* section is shared.

Answer (score 2):

The tab is on the homepage, not the `questions` section.

Click on the `Stack Overflow` logo and it will be there.